# Unable to increase height and width of UIView when using CGAffineTransformMakeRotation

Tags: swift, uiview, cgaffinetransform

I am rotating `UIView` by using `UISLider` Values. If slider values either get increase or decrease, according to that rotation happen. My code is working fine.

**Rotation Action:**

```
@IBAction func sliderToolAction(sender: UISlider) {

     if sender.tag == 1
     {
       let radians = CGFloat(sender.value) * 22 / (7 * 180)
       rotatingView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians)
     }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Rotating Frame:  (100, 20, 103.9990, 127.8889)
```

After rotating that `UIView`, I tried to increase `width` and `height` of that view, its not working.

**Resize Action**

```
@IBAction func sliderToolAction(sender: UISlider) {

     if sender.tag == 2
     {
       rotatingView.frame.size.width = CGFloat(sender.value) * viewWidth
       rotatingView.frame.size.height = CGFloat(sender.value) * viewHeight
     }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Rotating Frame:  (80, 40, 207.8888, 255.6667)  //ATTEMPT 1
Rotating Frame:  (50, 60, 207.8888, 255.6667)  //ATTEMPT 2
Rotating Frame:  (20, 90, 207.8888, 255.6667)  //ATTEMPT 3
Rotating Frame:  (-10, 120, 207.8888, 255.6667)  //ATTEMPT 4
```

I am increasing width and height alone, but UIView position is moving out of screen. Kindly guide me on this.

Comment: Why does "swift" have to be in the title? This is a framework question, and the tags already let people know you prefer an answer in Swift.

Comment: Yeah Ok... If u knw answer pls guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight from [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622621-frame):

> **Warning**
>
> If the transform property is not the identity transform, the value of
>   this property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.

and:

> Changes to this property can be animated. However, if the transform
>   property contains a non-identity transform, the value of the frame
>   property is undefined and should not be modified. In that case, you
>   can reposition the view using the center property and adjust the size
>   using the bounds property instead.

Instead of changing the frame size, change the bounds size.

Comment: Subviews not working. Only Superview gets increasing. Subview remains the same. Any idea ?? @Leo Natan

Comment: Have you set resize mask or constraints between your superview and subviews? Take note that AutoLayout has severe issues when rotation is involved, so your milage may vary.

Comment: S.. I m using autolay out and constraints

Comment: Don't rotate your UIView or don't use AL. `:-)` And make sure to open a bug report with Apple at https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Ok... Noted. Thanks

Comment: Having another doubt regarding this ?

Comment: Sure, I can help. What are your doubts?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40194355/uiimageview-rotation-is-not-working-when-using-cgaffinetransformmakerotation