# UIImageview rotation is not working when using CGAffineTransformMakeRotation

Tags: swift, uiview, uiimageview, cgaffinetransform

I am rotating `UIImageView` with `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation`. Rotation is working fine. When I tried to get that image to another `UIImageView` , rotation is not working.

**Coding 1:**

```
@IBAction func rotateAcn(sender: UIButton) {

rotatingImageVw.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.22)

}
```

**Output 1**

[image]

**Coding 2:**

```
@IBAction func getRotatedImage(sender: UIButton) {

newImageView.image = rotatingImageVw.image

}
```

**Output 2**

[image]

I dont know why this happening? I need **Output 2** as in **Output 1** .  Kindly guide me how to solve this?

Comment: Can you post some code....

Comment: One button action, CODE 1. Another button action CODE 2.

Comment: Do you familiar with corImage filters?

Comment: No. Can u guide me on this ?? Very tough

Comment: I have an idea to fix ur problem.but,I haven't tried this approached before.so it will take while to figure it out the answer.i recommend you to put a bounty on this question.so more people will get involved to answer your question and everyone get benefit.Make sure u need to update your post with proper code and content..cheers

Comment: You should use UIGesture to rotate your image and is the proper more conventional method for your project...

Comment: I just reading you question.b4 I update my answer.did you update the question again.it looks completely different...explain me on more on your comment.i want to make sure I understand right.

Comment: come for chat....

Answer (score 1):

Solution for Swift 5:

```
rotatingImageVw.transform = rotatingImageVw.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi / 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code:** Tested in Swift 3

**Note:** You didn't post the proper code. So, I made one for you.

**First VC:**

```
import UIKit

extension Double {
func toRadians() -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(self * .pi / 180.0) }  }

extension UIImage {
func rotated(by degrees: Double) -> UIImage? {
    guard let cgImage = self.cgImage else { return nil }

    let transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: degrees.toRadians())
    var rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: self.size).applying(transform)
    rect.origin = .zero

    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: rect.size)
    return renderer.image { renderContext in
        renderContext.cgContext.translateBy(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY)
        renderContext.cgContext.rotate(by: degrees.toRadians())
        renderContext.cgContext.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)

        let drawRect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: -self.size.width/2, y: -self.size.height/2), size: self.size)
        renderContext.cgContext.draw(cgImage, in: drawRect)
    }
   }
   }

class ViewController: UIViewController  {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!


override func viewDidLoad() { }

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "passImageData" {
        let dvc = segue.destination as! viewtwo

       let rotatedImage = imageView.image?.rotated(by: 45) // You workout the angle ypu want
        dvc.newImage = rotatedImage

    } 

}
```

**Second VC:**

```
   import Foundation
   import UIKit

   class viewtwo: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet weak var passedimage: UIImageView!

   var newImage: UIImage!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
   passedimage.image = newImage  
   }
   }
```

Comment: If I rotating using this method, some part of a image is disappeared. How can I get full image rotate? Like, "CGAffineTransformMakeRotation"  ??

Comment: I knew you will ask this..try passing output filter to CICrop filter that will fix the problem.From your question you haven't mentioned anything about the image zoom or crop size..my answer is what exactly you asked in your post...if you want me to proceed to update your request. First thing you have to give  up vote and we take it from there...

Comment: I have updated my code. This is two button acn. One thing, to rotate and antoher is to get that rotated image.

Comment: Still your update make no sense to me..let me clear.if you want to rotate and send the image to your 2vc with one action that's fine..play with my code answer already there.when you update your  post please mention you updated this piece of info.so my answer won't look insane to others...you got it

Comment: In Single VC, First Img Vw Frame [20, 30, 240, 128] and Second ImgVw Frame [20, 180, 240, 128]. Rotaing First Img Vw with CGAffine and Getting that rotated image to Second Img Vw. That s my task.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126434/discussion-between-mcdonal-11-and-joe).

Answer (score 0):

You are rotating the **image view**, not the image itself.
You need to get the transform to the new image view as well.

```
newImageView.transform = rotatingImageVw.transform
```

If you want to rotate the image itself, and not the view, you can to use [`CIImage.applying(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coreimage/ciimage/1438203-applying) and apply the transform on the image directly.